# Xamarin Android and Kotlin Library

Tags: android, xamarin.android, kotlin

I've working with Xamarin.Android , when i run project have exception Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError : Failed resolution of : Lkotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics;

Here is picture : 
[image]

How i can fix it ?

Comment: It's Kotlin a JVM language? How would Xamarin operate with that?

Comment: This error means Kotlin runtime library is not referneced, please see [this link](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-kotlin-jvm-internal-reflection/287). As far as I know, currently there is no official way to support kotlin in Xamarin.Android.

Comment: I believe that RWIL should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This error could indicate that your Xamarin code uses a native Android library or code that is written in **Kotlin**

Because the `Kotlin StdLib` is not packaged with the library, you should add `Xamarin.Kotlin.StdLib` in your `NuGet` packages of your Xamarin project so the Xamarin App can correctly interpret the library or code written in Kotlin

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, there's no official way to use Kotlin - which is Java Virtual Machine(JVM) language - with C# programming language, I mean Xamarin projects. If you're looking similar solution try to use F# programming language which may be a pretty similar to Kotlin